# Integrate 1/ln(ln(x)) asymptotically

Tags: integration, asymptotics

I was looking for the asymptotic behaviour of the anti-derivative of $\frac{1}{\ln \ln x}$, in terms of the big-O notation.

[Wikipedia's list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_integrals_of_logarithmic_functions) does not have this integral, and [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate%281%2Fln%28ln%28x%29%29%29) says "no results found in terms of standard mathematical functions".

For the similar function $\frac{1}{\ln x}$, the anti-derivative is asymptotically $\Theta(\frac{x}{\ln x})$. So it makes sense to assume (as Will Jagy commented) that here, too, the antiderivative is $\Theta(\frac{x}{\ln \ln x})$. This raises a more general question:

In what cases is this true that:

$$ \int{f(x)dx} = \Theta(x f(x)) $$

?

Comment: Possibly you don't need to actually evaluate the integral in order to answer that question. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: dominant term in an asymptotic series would be $x / \log \log x.$

Comment: @WillJagy I suspected this. But this is not always the case. In what cases is this true that $\int{f(x)dx} = \Theta(x f(x))$?

Comment: I' fiddling with it now. There is a whole discipline of writing asymptotic series for antiderivatives, one early book is Asymptotic Expansions by Erdelyi. I would expect this dominant term simply because $\log \log x$ changes so slowly.

Comment: alright, he says integrate by parts repeatedly...

Comment: @ErelSegal-Halevi Where can I find the proof for "For the similar function 1/lnx, the anti-derivative is asymptotically Θ(x/lnx). "? Thank you

Comment: @Sean it is here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithmic_integral_function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That worked, integration by parts, repeat while patience lasts and the things being integrated are getting smaller;
$$  u = \frac{1}{\log \log x}, \; \; \; dv = 1 \, dx $$
$$  du = \frac{-1}{x \log x \left( \log \log x \right)^2} dx, \; \;  v = x,$$
$$ \int \frac{1}{\log \log x} \; dx = \frac{x}{\log \log x} + \int  \frac{1}{  \left( \log \log x \right)^2 \;  \log x} dx $$

thinking about next step, but we can already see that the remaining integral is smaller than the original.

EDDDITTT: it seems repeating with $dv = 1 dx$ is the way to go.
$$ \int \frac{1}{\log \log x} \; dx = \frac{x}{\log \log x} + \frac{x}{  \left( \log \log x \right)^2 \;  \log x} + \int  \frac{1 + 2 \log \log x}{ 2 \; \left( \log \log x \right)^3 \; \left( \log x \right)^2} dx $$